# How can I upgrade my WSO2 Identity server version 4.5 to latest version directly?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How to upgrade my WSO2 Identity server version 4.5 to latest version directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current latest identity server version is IS-5.4.1. 
For your information, IS-5.5.0 is going to be released soon.

You can't migrate from 4.5.0 to latest version 5.4.1 straightly.

First you need to migrate your IS-4.5.0 to IS-5.0.0. You can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release for migration steps.

Then you can upgrade from 5.0.0 to 5.4.0 by changing the currentVersion and migrateVersion properties in migration-config.yaml. You can refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release for more information.

Then you can follow the documentation [updagrading from 5.4.0 to 5.4.1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release) to upgrade from WSO2 IS 5.4.0 to WSO2 IS 5.4.1

Comment: For upgrading to IS-5.5.0 can I upgrade from 5.0.0 to IS 5.5.0 by changing the currentVersion and migrateVersion properties in migration-config.yaml ?

Comment: I have missed one step in my answer. The recommended way is to migrate from 5.0.0 to 5.3.0, and then migrate from 5.3.0 to 5.5.0.

Comment: If I upgrade from 5.0.0 to 5.3.0, how the scripts of 5.1.0 and 5.2.0 will be updated ?

Comment: The Oauth which I created in the 4.5.0 version can be seen in the 5.0.0 by commenting the HideMenu tag in carbon.xml but from 5.1.0 onwards its not showing. How to migrate the Oauth to new versions ?